# unity - detect gameobjects that is already in contact

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, eventtrigger

Imagine I have 2 `gameobjects`, red plate and apple.
When game start(this is crucial), apple already on red plate(2 `gameobjects` already in contact). so if I move red plate, the apple is "parented" to red plate and follow the transform.

How can I do that in `Unity3D`? I look at the code `Trigger` and `Collision`, both of them need to at least a stage that 1 moving `gameobject` to collide the other, which I don't have that.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Will there ever be a game state where the red plate will not move with the apple?

Comment: @HappyApple there are, thus I have this situation that I need to solve. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution: `Bounds.Intersect`

As in:

```
var bounds1 = gameObject1.renderer.bounds;

var bounds2 = gameObject2.renderer.bounds;



if (bounds1.Intersects(bounds2))

{

    // do something

}
```

So with this, my problem solved.

Comment: Thanks so much! :D I prefer gameObject1.collider.bounds though, to make it independent of the graphics (at least I think it is).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest implementation is to use [OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) and [OnTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html) to toggle the parenting of one object's transform to another, so that all children of the parent will accept the transform operations performed on the parent.

**Example:**

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class
    PlateCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void
        Awake()
    {
        rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
        rigidbody.useGravity = false;
        collider.isTrigger = false;
    }
}
```

And

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SphereCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class 
    AppleCollider : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private void
        Awake()
    {
        rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
        rigidbody.useGravity = false;
        collider.isTrigger = false;
    }

    private void
        OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        PlateCollider tryGetPlate = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlateCollider>();

        if (tryGetPlate != null)
        {
            transform.parent = tryGetPlate.gameObject.transform;
        }
    }

    private void
        OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        PlateCollider tryGetPlate = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlateCollider>();

        if (tryGetPlate != null)
        {
            transform.parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

There's many other ways you can use to compare the two objects. In this example I try to get the component on a colliding gameobject and check if the component reference exists. Collision tags might be a better option for you, it might not.